# How to structure javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamic form where you can click a button and a new form row is added to the form.  The form entry looks like this:

```
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='".$f."' name='column_value_one' value='1'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='".$f."' name='column_value_two' value='2'>
```

For example, I add 3 lines of the above and data-index is 0 through 3. I try to process it by doing the following:

```
var data = [];
$(".custom").each(function() {
    var index = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
    data[index][$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});
```

I am trying to have an end result of:

```
data[0]['column_value_one'] = 1;
data[0]['column_value_two'] = 2;
data[1]['column_value_one'] = 1;
data[1]['column_value_two'] = 2;
```

I only usually write PHP, hence me laying out the array as per above.  But this would be a Javascript/Jquery array not PHP.

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the $f is generated by PHP loop for each set of two will have a new data-index id

Comment: What's the actual issue? It seems like using `map()` and the actual `index()` of the parent element may be a better solution over outputting a static value in each element from the server.

Comment: Find last input and add +1 value of last input on click

Comment: It gives me the response Cannot set property 'column_value_one' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init the `data[index]` to `{}` if the index does not exist.

```
data[index] = data[index] || {};
```

Like:

```js
var data = [];
$(".custom").each(function() {
  var index = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
  data[index] = data[index] || {}; 
  data[index][$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_one' value='1'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_two' value='2'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_one' value='1'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_two' value='2'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_one' value='1'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_two' value='2'>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an array of objects:

```
data = [
    {column_value_one: 1, column_value_two: 2},
    // ...
];
```

In that case, since the second input follows the first, you could do:

```
var data = $("input[name=column_value_one]").map(function() {
    return {column_value_one: this.value, column_value_two: $(this).next().val()};
}).get();
```

Live Example:

```js
var data = $("input[name=column_value_one]").map(function() {
    return {column_value_one: this.value, column_value_two: $(this).next().val()};
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_one' value='11'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_two' value='12'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_one' value='21'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_two' value='22'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_one' value='31'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_two' value='32'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you may have something in-between them, use two jQuery objects:

```
var ones = $("input[name=column_value_one]");
var twos = $("input[name=column_value_two]");
var data = ones.map(function(index) {
    return {column_value_one: this.value, column_value_two: twos.eq(index).val()};
}).get();
```

```js
var ones = $("input[name=column_value_one]");
var twos = $("input[name=column_value_two]");
var data = ones.map(function(index) {
    return {column_value_one: this.value, column_value_two: twos.eq(index).val()};
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_one' value='11'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='0' name='column_value_two' value='12'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_one' value='21'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='1' name='column_value_two' value='22'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_one' value='31'>
<input type='text' class='custom' data-index='2' name='column_value_two' value='32'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In both cases, there's no need for `data-index` (for this; maybe you need it for something else).

Comment: Thanks TJ, got a solution.  Appreciate the response though.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy - Just added a second one as well. (And unless you need it for something else, there's no need for `data-index`.)